# Upload web content in liferay on a with a custom date

Tags: liferay-6

We are having a requirement to upload the web contents in back date. In other words, We want to give the user an option set the date of web content by himself while publishing the web content.

What can be the approach to get it done??
We are using LR 6.0.6.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Wich date you are mean: create date, modification date, publishing date? What do you want to do with this date? Show for portal users?

Comment: We mean create date, we want to show it for portal users.This date will define for which date the news article was..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the date for portal users, you should use modification-date instead of creation-date. In the cms-template you can access to the modification-date with `$reserved-article-modified-date.getData()`.

See:
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Journal+Template+%28Velocity%29

https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Velocity+Variables+Available+in+Web+Content

Comment: Dear Mark.. Still there is no option (by velocity variables) to set the date while saving (publishing) the web contents. We want to set the create date when the web content is the first time the published..

Comment: That is possible to change the creation date, but I mean that is not good :) If the requirement is to show to portal user date of publishing (modification) than use simple the modification date of article.

Comment: Or do you have some other requirements to change the creation date?

Answer (score 1):

There is one option in Liferay that custom fields, go to control panel custom fields option in left side menu. Add one custom field for webcontent, then set the article-modifeid-date.getData()[given in above post] to user's selected date as per that input field.

You can get the value of custom fields in "expandoValues" table of DB, and by code you can get the code by using expandoBridge class.

it may help you, http://liferayknowledgeshare.blogspot.in/

in that post look @ "Adding custom field in registration page is Liferay" topic

Answer (score 0):

To change the creation date of article you can create a Liferay-Hook and observe the journal-article-update-event, see:

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/extend-override-portal-properties-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en

put to the portal.properties of your hook something like this:

```
value.object.listener.com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle=com.my.cms.ChangeArticleCreationDate
```

and create a class

```
public class ChangeArticleCreationDate extends BaseModelListener<JournalArticle> {

    @Override
    public void onAfterUpdate(JournalArticle jk) throws ModelListenerException {
              ...
    }
}
```